# VS 2015 Shared Project causes Type exists in both X assembly and Y assembly (CS0433)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to implement a common attribute type and corresponding enum type to be included in AssemblyInfo.cs for every project, for use as metadata.  All projects in my solution will require the attribute.

I have created a Visual Studio 2015 Shared Project and included these types.

Subsequently, I referenced the Shared Project in some base level assemblies, which contain no interdependencies. However, if I include two or more of these assemblies as references in larger projects, I receive the "type exists in both X assembly and Y assembly" (CS0433)

Am I implementing the Shared Project incorrectly? Is this a bad approach to solve the stated task?

Comment: One thing that seems to work is to have a single class library that references the Shared Project. Then that assembly can be referenced by the other dependencies.   However, why should I have to create a separate library to be referenced?  That's the point of trying to implement the Shared Project in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have two `using` statements at the top, which contain classes with identical names.  There are two possible ways to deal with this.

1. Remove one (or both) `using` references and type the class names and types long-hand.

Example:

```
//using System.Data.SqlClient;
//using System.Data.OleDbClient;

var p1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.Parameter();
var p2 = new System.Data.OleDbClient.Parameter();
```

or

2. Alias both `using` references. You will still have to qualify your class names, but you can use the alias instead of full long-hand.

Example:

```
using Db1 = System.Data.SqlClient;
using Db2 = System.Data.OleDbClient;

var p1 = new Db1.Parameter();
var p2 = new Db2.Parameter();
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have stumbled upon an answer.  I had my Shared Project types declared under their own namespaces.

When I removed the namespace block from the code, the code compiled correctly.

I'm not sure if this a legitimate fix to the problem, but it seems to make the compiler happy.

Comment: This is NOT a fix.  I still ran into the problem later on with a different child project.